# View nearby BLE devices

Tags: connectiq

I'd like to find any BLE devices within range of a Garmin ConnectIQ enabled watch.

Is there anyway on a Garmin ConnectIQ device (e.g. Forerunner 235) to scan for nearby BLE devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this using the existing watch API calls as of ConnectIQ SDK 2.2.1 which was released on November 8, 2016. Instead you would have to write a companion mobile app (for Android and/or iOS) which you would then use to find nearby devices. The mobile app could then pass on whatever information needed and in turn carry out actions based on input from the watch.

See more details on companions apps here:

- https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/android-sdk-guide/
- https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/ios-sdk-guide/